# I want to stop specific customer group to buy not more than two products and also stop on specific amount of cart in magento2

Tags: php, oop, magento, e-commerce, magento2

I want to stop specific customer group from buying not more than two products. Also I need to stop them on specific amount in cart.
Is that possible if yes then what is the best possible way to do that observer, plugin or prefrence?
If anyone had done it before please share your solutions.

I have tried to do it by plugin by stopping add to cart but the page reloads and im not able to show the exception message.

```
<?php
namespace CustomPlugin\CartProductRestriction\Plugin\Cart;

use Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class RestrictCartQty
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(Add $subject, callable $proceed)
    {

        $allowedCustomerGroup = 4;
        $customerGroupId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();

        if ($customerGroupId == $allowedCustomerGroup) {


            $itemCount = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

            if ($itemCount >= 2) {
                $message = __('You can only add 2 items to your cart.');
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                return $subject;
            }
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//di.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="limit_cart_items_plugin_name" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Quote\ClassName" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>

//YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Quote
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ClassName
{
    public function beforeBeforeSave(Quote $subject)
    {
        $customerGroupId = $subject->getCustomerGroupId();

        // Define the customer group(s) you want to restrict
        $restrictedCustomerGroups = [1, 3];

        // Check if the customer group is in the restricted list
        if (in_array($customerGroupId, $restrictedCustomerGroups)) {
            // Get the items in the cart
            $items = $subject->getAllItems();

            // Define the maximum number of items allowed in the cart
            $maxItemsAllowed = 2;

            // Define the maximum cart total amount and here get specific amount
            $maxCartTotal = 120; 

            $totalQty = 0;
            $cartTotal = 0;
            $itemsToRemove = [];

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $totalQty += $item->getQty();
                $cartTotal += $item->getRowTotal();

                // Check if the item quantity exceeds the limit
                if ($item->getQty() > $maxItemsAllowed) {
                    $itemsToRemove[] = $item;
                }
            }

            // Check if the cart exceeds the limits
            if ($totalQty > $maxItemsAllowed || $cartTotal > $maxCartTotal) {
                // Remove extra items
                foreach ($itemsToRemove as $itemToRemove) {
                    $subject->removeItem($itemToRemove->getId());
                }
                throw new LocalizedException(__('You can only add up to 2 products to your cart. and maximum amount 120.'));
            }
        }

        return [$subject]; 
    }
}
```